# Python: Reference to a class generically in an instance method?

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages

This question is similar, but it pertains to static methods: [In Python, how do I reference a class generically in a static way, like PHP's "self" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738467/in-python-how-do-i-reference-a-class-generically-in-a-static-way-like-phps-se)

How do you refer to a class generically in an instance method?

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class a:
    b = 'c'
    def __init__(self):
        print(a.b) # <--- not generic because you explicitly refer to 'a'

    @classmethod
    def instance_method(cls):
        print(cls.b) # <--- generic, but not an instance method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **old-style classes** (if your code is Python 2.x code, and your class in not inheriting from `object`), use the [`__class__` property](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

```
def __init__(self):
    print(self.__class__.b) # Python 2.x and old-style class
```

For **new-style classes** (if your code is Python 3 code), use [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

```
def __init__(self):
    print(self.__class__.b) # __class__ works for a new-style class, too
    print(type(self).b)
```

Internally, `type` uses the [`__class__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) property.

Comment: I assumed this was Python 3 code (who in their right mind would use old-style classes *by choice*?). Updated with an explanation for python 2. If you want to support both old-style **and** new-style classes, use `__class__`.

Comment: +1 Verified this is correct when not inheriting from object on 2.7. Why would someone prefer to use type() over \_\_class\_\_?

Comment: @pokstad: It doesn't have lots of underscores :D Also, the object may do stupid things and override `__class__`, but it can't fool `type`.

Comment: @pokstad `__class__` is (like all properties of the form `__foo__`) an internal Python property, and one is not supposed to mess with those - in theory, they can change over time. For example, an advanced interpreter (like [PyPy](http://pypy.org/)) may not even store the class when it can statically or dynamically determine that the value is constant. In contrast, `type` is a well-documented function that will never go away.

Comment: @lunixbochs I'm sorry, to what example are you referring? The [first one](http://phihag.de/2011/so/py2-type.py) works in  Python2.4, 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7 for me. From the [linked offical documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes): `if x is an instance of an old-style class, then x.__class__ designates the class of x`.

Comment: ignore that :) was a context issue.